# Create an IPA file with ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, provisioning-profile, ipa

I'm trying to compile my ionic app for iOS.
It compiles well with the simulator, so I'd like to test it on some friend's iDevices (I don't have any iphone or ipad), so I'd like to send them the IPA in order to test.

To do that I saw that I have to archive my project, I tried to do so and I got an error:

**Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.**

I checked my profile, XCode suggests me to fix the issue. But when I try to do so, I got this error:

**Creating a provisioning profile requires one or more devices to be registered with your team.  Connect a device to your Mac to add it to your team.**

So I thought that having an iDevice wasn't mandatory in order to compile for iOS. Am I wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have apple developer account ?? Don't confuse with apple id !

Comment: Yes, in recent times you don't require signing identities for running on device. Set your apple id in build settings of your xcode.

Comment: If you have your friend device with you, connect to mac and then run. Using your personal apple id would be preferable.

Comment: Here is a detailed article on how to run on the device without signing identities.

http://blog.ionic.io/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/

Comment: Thanks, so developer account is needed even for testing the app on devices that can't be connected to my xcode ?

Answer (score 2):

You required provisioning profile to archive your project to make build. Now if you don't have create provisioning profile from your apple developer account, then you have option `automatic`, but to generate `provisioning profile` you required your device connected with your xcode,so that xcode takes `udid` of that device and can make automatic provisioning profile!

Now, if you don't have real device then from your developer account - Add some device first - I mean your friend's device(for that you required udid of it!) - create `provisioning profile for development` - download it - set it as provisioning profile from `general` or build `settings` from your xcode. Then you will able to make build!

If you have device then also you need to create provisioning profile that contains your friend's device, other wise application will not install on it!

You can refer [Raywenderlich's tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/127936/submit-an-app-part-1) to manage these kind of stuff that i have mentioned above!

Comment: Thanks, so if they are not in the same country as me (so I can't connect their phones to my xcode), there's no way for they to test my app ?

Comment: No! There is no way! Because you required to add device in your provisioning profile or xcode can create automatic provisioning profile and add connected device to it!

Comment: Oh ok, that's clear, thanks ! :) So I have to post it on the store if I want them to test it ?
And can I post an app on the store even if I only tested it on an emulator (so no real device, as I don't have any) ?

Comment: Yes,you can post your app on app store if you haven't tested on real device but it's good practice to test app on real device to know that it is working properly or not!